# (Grafakos 2.2.12) Prove that all Schwartz functions $f$ on $\Bbb R^n$ satisfy this inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty $ and let $p'$ thus $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'}=1$.

$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n)$ is the Schwartz space defined as the class of all $C^\infty$ functions $\varphi:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}|x^\beta \partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|<\infty,$$ for all multi-indices $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb N^n$

Prove that all Schwartz functions $f$ on $R^n$ satisfy this inequality

$$\|f\|_{\infty}^2 \leq \sum_{|\alpha + \beta|=n} \|\partial^\alpha f\|_p\|\partial^\beta f\|_{p^{'}}$$
where the sum is taken over all pairs of multi-indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$ whose sum has size $n$.

My try:

I have already proved that $\|f\|_{\infty}^2 \leq 2\|f\|_p \|f\|_{p^{'}}$ but I don't know how to continue. Could someone help me?

**I am allowed to use only the theorems a definitions of that chapter of the book.**

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Where is this coming from

Comment: Is exercise 2.2.12 of "Classical Fourier Analysis" by Grafakos, page 118. @DavidRaveh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Proof in one sentence:* it follows from Sobolev's inequality for $f^2$ and the multinomial theorem.

*Details:* Let me use the multi-index notation. For any $\gamma = (\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n)\in\Bbb N^n$, let $|\gamma| = \gamma_1+\dots+\gamma_n$. It follows from Sobolev's inequalities that
$$
\|f\|_{L^\infty}^2 = \|f^2\|_{L^\infty} \leq \int_{\Bbb R^n} |\nabla^n(f^2)|\leq \int_{\Bbb R^n} \sum_{|\gamma|=n}|\partial^\gamma(f^2)|.
$$
On the other hand, it follows from the Leibniz formula that
$$
\sum_{|\gamma|=n}|\partial^\gamma(f^2)| = \sum_{|\gamma|=n}\left|\sum_{\alpha+\beta=\gamma} \partial^\alpha f \, \partial^\beta f\right| \leq \sum_{|\alpha+\beta|=n}\left|\partial^\alpha f \, \partial^\beta f\right|.
$$
To conclude, use the Fubini theorem and Hölder's inequality to get
$$
\|f\|_{L^\infty}^2 \leq \sum_{|\alpha+\beta|=n} \int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|\partial^\alpha f \, \partial^\beta f\right|\leq \sum_{|\alpha+\beta|=n} \|\partial^\alpha f\|_{L^p}\, \|\partial^\beta f\|_{L^{p'}}.
$$

Comment: The solution you provide uses formulas and inequalities(Sobolev's) that are more advanced given the book chapter.

Comment: No, in this case this Sobolev inequality is easy, it is just the fundamental theorem of calculus used $n$ times. Example for $n=2$, since $f$ vanishes at infinity,
$$
f(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^x \partial_x f(x',y)\,\mathrm d x' = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y \partial_y\partial_x f(x',y')\,\mathrm d x'\,\mathrm d y'
$$
so
$$
|f(x,y)| \leq \iint_{\Bbb R^2} |\partial_y\partial_x f(x',y')|\,\mathrm d x'\,\mathrm d y'
$$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\nabla^{n}f$?

Comment: The application $\nabla$ iterated $n$ times, this gives the tensor $\nabla^n f = (\partial_{k_1}\dots\partial_{k_n}f)_{0\leq k_1,\dots, k_n\leq n}$